# meaning of "so kann es"

Tags: meaning, translation

The full sentence is:

> So kann es durchaus auch viele lebenslange Ehen geben.

What I think of the meaning: So there could be many lifelong marriages.

The precendence sentence is:

> Das heißt auch: Wer sich nicht trennen will, kann zu einer Verlängerung der Ehe aktiv "Ja" sagen.

I need help with the phrase "So kann es".
thanks.

Comment: Danke @Herr Schölnast

Comment: I'd rather translate it as "So there may absolutely be many lifelong marriages too".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would translate this sentence as

> This way there can absolutely be many lifelong marriages.

Or, even easier

> So there can absolutely be many lifelong marriages.

So, combined with the preceding sentence, this would say

> This also means: Someone who does not want to break up can actively say "yes" to  keeping the marriage. This way there can absolutely be many lifelong marriages.

Answer (score 1):

> So **kann es** durchaus auch viele lebenslange Ehen **geben**.

So, by all means, **there may be** many life-long marriages.

This *es kann geben* almost always means *there may be*. The one notable exception is when you talk about a specific thing or person mentioned in a sentence before, which is able to give something.

> Es (das Navigationsgerät) kann ihnen auch Empfehlungen zur Stauumfahrung geben.

Answer (score 0):

So lifelong marriages are thorough possible.

So in my opinion "so kann es" means, that something is (because of xy) thorough possible.
But I think there are many other ways you can put it, too.